# How to get the objectKey "Title" from a Dictionary inside of an Array (Array of Dictionaries)

Tags: uisearchbar

I'm trying  make this code which is from a Dictionary of Arrays (CODE) from an Array of Dictionaries.   My .plist is one Array (Rows) and is full of Dictionaries. But I just can't call the Titles inside those dictionaries correctly, it's crash after crash.   All of this is to implement a Search Bar.  Thank you

[CODE] //---copy all the movie titles in the dictionary into the listOfMovies array--- 
listOfMovies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
for (NSString *year in array)   //---get all the years---

{
     //---get all the movies for a particular year--- 
     NSArray *movies = [movieTitles objectForKey:year]; 
     for (NSString *title in movies)
     {
      [listOfMovies addObject:title];
     }
}

[/CODE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the "Title" of the dictionary try the property:

```
myDictionary.description
```